# Android Licensing Generating DeviceID

Tags: android, licensing, uuid, policy, deviceid

For the licensing of my app I need a deviceID. I already setup the necessary things:

**Setting up the licenseChecker:**

```
licenseChecker = new LicenseChecker(
    context, new ServerManagedPolicy(context,
    new AESObfuscator(SALT, context.getPackageName(), id())),
    BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY
);
```

**Generating the deviceID:**

```
 public synchronized String id() {
        if (uniqueID == null) {
            SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
            uniqueID = sharedPrefs.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, null);

            if (uniqueID == null) {
                uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
                editor.putString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueID);
                editor.commit(); 
            }
        }

        return uniqueID;
    }
```

But I still have some questions regarding the deviceID I generate in id().
P.S. It's a chargeable app.

**My goals:**

- The user can use the app on every device he has that is linked to the google play account he acquired the app with
- The user can remove the app from his device and later install it again. So the license is permanent

**Does my code support that?**

**Links:**

[Unique ID](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids.html)

[Licensing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/adding-licensing.html#app-obfuscation)

Comment: I think this is the wrong approach for your exact needs because device IDs have nothing to do with accounts and are not the same even when you reinstall the same ROM. Plus, you are not getting the device ID, but just a random number

Comment: @Chisko Check out the first link^^

Comment: OK, that talks about app instance ID, not device ID. If the user has not downloaded your app it will be hard to hard to get the app instance. Google already handles having your app synced across devices. You might want to tie your licence to an email address